# Hover map poly to show extra div on map

Tags: css

trying to show div #status-lokal1 after hover on map poly #lokal1
I am looking for a solution using only css. Can't trigger div to be visible.

```
#status-lokal1 {display:none; position: relative;}
#lokal1:hover  #status-lokal1 {display:block !important; position:relative; bottom:5rem; right:0; z-index:999999}



     <div  data-mh="mappa" class="baner-inwestycje mh2">
    <div class="row expanded"> 
        <div class="sop1" >  
            <img src="img/inwestycje-budowlane/new-forest-boleslawice/plan/new-forest-plan-osiedla-slupsk.jpg" id="map-height"/> 
            <img src="img/inwestycje-budowlane/new-forest-boleslawice/plan/new-forest-plan-osiedla-slupsk_0019_Warstwa-1.png" class="auf"> 
            <img  data-mh="mappa" src="img/inwestycje-budowlane/new-forest-boleslawice/plan/empty.png" class="auf-empty mh2" alt="" usemap="#map" id="map-img"> 
        </div>

              <div id="status-lokal1"><h3>sprzedane</h3></div>

      <map name="map" id="location-map4" class="show-for-landscape">
        <area shape="poly" data-open="lokal1" id="lokal1" coords="" href="#" alt="">
      </map>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to not use a `<map>` element, but to use CSS to position elements over areas on interest in an image. That way you can use a nice semantic, accessible list (`<ul>`).

Here are some articles which explain the technique:

- http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap/
- http://www.frankmanno.com/ideas/css-imagemap-redux/
- http://www.cssplay.co.uk/articles/imagemap/
- http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/solar_map
- https://alistapart.com/article/imagemap

Comment: Gotta be a map. It's an interactive element hard to rebuild:
https://www.porters.pl/osiedle-new-forest-boleslawice.php

Comment: Then you'll have to use JS, which you're using already, to achieve your goal.